# What is the relationship between `.Random.seed` and `ls()`?

Tags: r, jupyter-irkernel

When doing `load("files.RData"); ls()` the output printed to the console is:

```
'File1'   'File2'   'File3'
```

When doing `(load("files.RData"))` (the point of the parentheses around `load()` being to indicate to R to print the output of that line) the output printed to the console is:

```
'.Random.seed'   'File1'   'File2'   'File3'
```

**Question:** What is the reason for this difference?

**Note:** This might be specific to IRkernel since this code is being run in a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: @MauritsEvers If there aren't any parentheses around it, it doesn't print anything to console. So there actually is a point. The point literally being exactly what I said the point was.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I did answer your questions. Run it in a Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `help("ls")`, we can see the purpose of the `all.names` argument to `ls()`, which has a default value of `FALSE`:

```
all.names: a logical value.  If ‘TRUE’, all object names are returned.
          If ‘FALSE’, names which begin with a ‘.’ are omitted.
```

So, in your first example, `ls()` will not print `.Random.seed`; it begins with a `.`.

Now let us consider the "Value" sections of the help files for `load`:

```
A character vector of the names of objects created, invisibly.
```

and `Paren`:

```
For ‘(’, the result of evaluating the argument.  This has
 visibility set, so will auto-print if used at top-level.
```

So, in your second example, `load("files.RData")` invisibly returns "A character vector of the names of objects created" (even `.Random.seed`), but `(` auto-prints that character vector, even including `.Random.seed`.

#### What even is `.Random.seed`?

First, we can see what it *is* by looking at `help(".Random.seed")`:

```
 ‘.Random.seed’ is an integer vector, containing the random number
 generator (RNG) *state* for random number generation in R.  It can
 be saved and restored, but should not be altered by the user.
```

It will pop up in your global environment any time you use one of R's pseudo-random number generators. For example, in a fresh R session, I can do the following:

```
x <- 1
ls(all.names = TRUE)
# [1] "x"

rnorm(1)
# [1] 2.378572

ls(all.names = TRUE)
# [1] ".Random.seed" "x"
```

Then I can save any or all of these R objects via `save()`:

```
save(x, file = "one.RData")
save(.Random.seed, file = "two.RData")
save(x, .Random.seed, file = "all.RData")
# or, equivalently in this case,
# save(list = ls(all.names = TRUE), file = "all.RData")
```

If I use `save.image()`, *everything* in my global environment is saved, even files beginning with `.` -- according to the help file, it's a shortcut for `save(list = ls(all.names = TRUE), file = ".RData", envir = .GlobalEnv)`.

So, wherever you got the `files.RData` from, they either used `save.image()`, or intentionally included their `.Random.seed` object when saving `files.RData`.

Comment: Oh neat -- so `load` is creating `.Random.seed`?

Comment: Actually, `.Random.seed` is an object saved in `files.RData`, so `load()` creates it only when the file loaded contains it; I would guess that `files.RData` was created via `save.image()`. I can add in a bit explaining what that is soon.

Comment: Oh OK cool -- thanks so much for this! (FYI I didn't create `files.RData` so I don't know how it was made/what was put into it.)

Comment: @Chill2Macht Some further explanation about `.Random.seed`, etc., is added.

Comment: Whenever you exist a session, and save the session, .Rdata file is created